# Реализация классов на php

Tags: классы, php

здравствуйте, хочу реализовать следующее:
на странице пользователь вводит тект который через пост передается в класс, в этом классе публичная функция принимает этот текст и обрабатывает его, затем хочу результат передать другой функции и вывести ее туда куда мне нужно

```
class TZ {
    public $shablon;

    function tz () {
        $text = $this->shablon;
        echo $text;
    }

    public function str($text) {
        {обрабатывающий код}
        return $this->shablon = $text;
    }
}

$tz = new TZ;

$tz->tz();

if (isset($_POST['go'])){
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $tz->str($text);
}
```

не получается вывести, показывает пустой результат...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю это

```
$tz = new TZ;
$tz->tz();

if ( isset($_POST['go']) ){
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $tz->str($text);
}
```

Нужно заменить на это

```
if ( isset($_POST['go']) ){
    $tz = new TZ;
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $tz->str($text);
    $tz->tz();
}
```

Или можно еще так сделать чтобы вывелась переменная

```
if ( isset($_POST['go']) ){
        $tz = new TZ;
        $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
        $string = $tz->str($text);
        echo $string;
}
```

Тут много разных вариантов может быть.

Comment: а если вывод нужно делать в другом файле через шаблонизатор, файл подключается в индекс.пхп?

Answer (score 0):

на момент вызова метода $tz->tz(); в public $shablon; ничего нет, потому он выводит пустоту.

надо так:

```
if (isset($_POST['go'])){
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$tz = new TZ;    
$tz->str($text);
$tz->tz();
```

1: Стоит переименовать метод **str** в **setShablon**

2: Писать *Shablon* - не тру, лучше заменить на англоязычное *Template*, тогда метод будет называться **setTemplate**

Comment: а если вывод нужно делать в другом файле через шаблонизатор, файл подключается в индекс.пхп?